# Linq outer join possible issue

Tags: c#, linq, tdd

```
        var query1 = from l in context.Logs
                    where l.LogID == maxid
                    select l;
        int count1 = query1.Count();

        var query2 = from ld in context.LogDetails
                     where ld.LogID == maxid
                     select ld;
        int count2 = query2.Count();

        Assert.AreEqual(1,count1);
        Assert.AreEqual(0,count2);
```

I wish I could write the above query in a better way. If I were using TSQL, I could use OUTER JOIN and filter to see if ld.LogID was null. But I do not know how to do that in LINQ. Is there any way I could clean this up?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Outer joins are possible in LINQ](https://www.google.com/search?q=outer+join+linq).

```
var query = from log in context.Logs
            join logDetail in context.LogDetails
                on log.LogID = logDetail.LogID into lj
            from item in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { log.LogID, MissingDetails = lj == null };
```

Comment: so how can I write Assert in one line to check for only 1 record in log table and 0 record in logDetails? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outer join using navigation properties:

```
from log in context.Logs
from logDetail in log.LogDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {log, logDetail}
```

Don't forget to test logdetail for null.

Comment: David, shouldn't Logs and LogDetails be joined some how?

Comment: David, this query is not compiling.

Comment: Open the dbml.  Add an association from Log to LogDetail with the appropriate IDs.  Now the dbml will generate a navigation property on each of those classes:  Log.LogDetails and LogDetail.Log